# limit of $x^2e^{-{x^{-3}}}$ doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to show that the limit when $x$ goes to zero of the function $f(x)=x^2e^{-(x^{-3})}$ doesn't exist. My intuition says that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^2e^{-(x^{-3})}=0 $$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}x^2e^{-(x^{-3})}=\infty$$

but I am not sure how to prove it. I've tried L'hopitals rule for the last one but it gets really messy.

Comment: whe for $x< 0$ then $-(x^{-3}) = \frac 1{|x|^3}\to \infinty$ and $|x|^2e^{\frac 1{|x|^3}}\to \infty$.  And if $x > 0$ then $-(x^{-3}) =-\frac 1{|x|^3}$ .....

Comment: you instincts are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the replacement $t = \frac{-1}{x}$, then you have
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} x^{2}e^{-x^{-3}} = 
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{e^{t^{3}}}{t^{2}} =
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{3t^{2}e^{t^{3}}}{2t} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{3te^{t^{3}}}{2} = \infty$$

Your intuition about $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}$ is of course correct because in this case both $x^{2}$ and $e^{-x^{-3}}$ both go to 0.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Set $u=1/x$. This is a relatively common trick to keep in mind. Then $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^2e^{-(x^{-3})}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{e^{-u^3}}{u^2}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}x^2e^{-(x^{-3})}=\lim_{u\to-\infty}\frac{e^{-u^3}}{u^2}$$

I wouldn't try L'Hopital's on either of these either, but perhaps these are easier to analyze.